# Change axis of rotation (animated)

Tags: animation, axis

I want to rotate an object around some axis during one period in my animation and rotate it around another axis during another period.

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Example: flip dice from 6 to 5 and then from 5 to 3 by rotating around the edge which is staying on the ground.